# Import Error: "No module named 'dateutil' "

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-dateutil

I installed  Python-Dateutil package, but when i import it in my script , it's throwing error:

import dateutil
ImportError: No module named 'dateutil'

when i checked the lib folder, dateutil.eggs files are there , because of this i can not run matplotlib module.  Please provide a solution.

Comment: Whether or not you have some eggs is not important. Is the package installed? How did you install it?

Comment: I downloaded the source file and in command prompt gave the command as: "python setup.py install. "

Comment: This is the prompt :-----C:\.................\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\dateutil-2.3>python setup.py install...    please tell me if anything is wrong.@ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: That should be fine. Do you have a `Lib\site-packages\dateutil` folder? Usually you do not need to install it manually though, `pip install dateutil` or similar.

Comment: No I can't do that, because my system is running  behind firewall. It can't download dateutil on its own. I have to install it manually. And no there is no dateutil folder inside the the path you given. Only .egg file of dateutil is there. if you want i can share the cmd prompt  after the installation is done.

Answer (score 18):

Python 3+

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
```

Python 2

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the anaconda

open anaconda prompt (go to start and search anaconda  prompt)
type the following command on prompt

> `conda install -c anaconda dateutil`

if you are using python 3.x version

> `pip3 install python-dateutil`

if you are using python 2 version

> `pip2 install python-dateutil`

Answer (score 0):

do you have multiple python version on your computer ?
python 2.7 and 3.5 for example.
maybe there is a confusion here.

or even multiple version of python 3.5 ?

i often have this problem when I forget which python I am using.

Comment: Yes you are right . I have installed python 2.7.14 and 3.5 versions .So is there problem due to this ?? Should i uninstall other version and try to install dateutil again?

Comment: there is no problem.
just make sure that you are trying to import when running the same version of python that the one where you did the install

Answer (score -1):

## Installation dateutil

The dateutil module provides powerful extensions to the standard datetime module, available in Python.

1. **Install from PyPI using pip**

   pip install python-dateutil
2. **Download from PyPI**

   https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/

Comment: If you read the original question properly, you would note that the poster has already detailed that they have installed the package.